# How can I force Mac Catalyst to use my "Toggle Sidebar" UIKeyCommand shortcut?

Tags: mac-catalyst

I have a Mac Catalyst app with a sidebar that can be shown/hidden via a Mac menu.  This works as expected on Catalina. However, on Monterey the menu item works but the keyboard shortcut is changed to a system default. I want it to use my input sequence, not the system's.

The menu item is created in the app delegate:

```swift
let toggleSidebar =
  UIKeyCommand(title: NSLocalizedString("Toggle Sidebar", comment: "MainMenu"),
               action: #selector(MenuCommands.toggleSidebar),
               input: "1", modifierFlags: [.command])
builder.insertChild(UIMenu(options: [.displayInline], children: [toggleSidebar]),
                           atStartOfMenu: .view)
```

And the view controller updates the menu item text:

```swift
override func validate(_ command: UICommand) {
  if command.action == #selector(toggleSidebar) {
    command.title = labelForToggleSidebar()
  }
  super.validate(command)
}
```

How can I force my UIKeyCommand shortcut to be used?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that macOS Monterey added a standard menu item  that invokes the `toggleSidebar` selector, and it ignores attempts to add additional UIKeyCommands with the same selector.

My solution is to remove the system command before adding mine:

```swift
let toggleSidebar =
  UIKeyCommand(title: NSLocalizedString("Toggle Sidebar", comment: "MainMenu"),
               action: #selector(MenuCommands.toggleSidebar),
               input: "1", modifierFlags: [.command])
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
  builder.remove(menu: .sidebar)
}
builder.insertChild(UIMenu(options: [.displayInline], children: [toggleSidebar]),
                    atStartOfMenu: .view)
```